# Odd Kivy behavior on mouse event Ubuntu mate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouseevent, kivy

I've run into a weird behavior on Ubuntu mate when using kivy. For any app that I try to run when I click with a mouse I get second clicks in adjacent positions. That happens only on Ubuntu mate, for the app that I am developing(that works fine on windows) as well as any others(tried two others from online examples). I'm really new to programming and google gave me nothing this time.

The image shows what happens in a calculator app when I try clicking in the button 4 it also selects button 3.

[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJIUU.png)

I realize that this is not a greatly asked question, but I really don't have a clue on how to attack this issue.

Can anyone please point me a direction where to look for problems like this or is there anyone that have seen something like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure `config.ini` which is in your `.kivy` folder.
Go down to `[input]` and make sure it looks like this:

```
[input]
mouse = mouse
%(name)s = probesysfs
```

Comment: @Thiago you are wellcome